# My payout function to lottery winners is failing. I'm storing the winners in an array and attempting to payout but getting reverts

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

the code:

```
    function payoutWinners() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= payoutOwed, "send more than what is owed");

        for (uint i = 0; i < winningAddresses.length; i++) {
            payable(winningAddresses[i].wallet).transfer(winningAddresses[i].amount);
        }
    }
```

winning addresses struct:

```
    struct Winner {
        address wallet;
        uint amount;
    }
```

the amount paid out depends on the amount that the user wagered so this value is calculated. WinningAddresses is a dynamic array.

I am getting revert failures when deploying. The errors are not clear either. It is simply a JSON RPC fail error.

```
transact to LottoTest.testPayoutWinners errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

This function does work when I use msg.value in place of winningAddresses[i].amount but that is incorrect logic as that would pay out a static value per winningAddress rather than the previously calculated amount.

Any help on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated. I am still fairly new to Solidity so thanks in advance.

**ALSO** I have already tested the balance on the smart contract and the msg.value being sent. They are more than the amount that is owed to each wallet in my test.

Comment: How many addresses are in that array??

Comment: @Sky I tested with only one address.

Answer (score 0):

I would need more of your code to be sure. But it looks like the `winningAddresses` array might be so large that the `gas costs` of running your transactions is hitting `blockGasLimit` causing the transaction to revert

Comment: I have been only testing with one address in the array

Comment: Do you have the balance to payout the winners?

Comment: Just ended up solving this. It's because functions were being called from a test contract. Therefore the test contract's SHA was being set in all msg.sender values. Therefore when it came time to transfer it was attempting to transfer to itself which caused a revert.